# OVH хостинг и подключение к бд в Java EE JDBC

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Хостинг MyOVH. Есть доменное имя. Есть созданная база данных. У этой базы есть свой адрес (Server Address). Подключил JDBC драйвер. Указал данные для подключения к бд - указал `Server Address`. Но при подключении пишет ошибку
`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: database.mysql.db`

Хотя на `php` всё нормально подключается. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Первое, что я бы вам посоветовал - попробовать достучаться до сервиса (ping/telnet). Хотя, откровенно говоря, начальных данных маловато...